# Login facebook right in app with Embedded WebView Login Dialog

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-login

I read facebook docs and find some ways to login facebook. How to login with  Embedded WebView Login Dialog with FB sdk 3.5.x

[Link facebook docs here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/iossdk/login/#webview)

Comment: R u asking any question ?or providing the sol how to use facebook.

Comment: I mean how to login facebook in my app with a embedded webview, not using safari or facebook native app.

Comment: please check the below code

Answer (score 0):

It may be usefull to you and few delegate methods of facebook are also shown below

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    return [facebook handleOpenURL:url];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Although the SDK attempts to refresh its access tokens when it makes API calls,
    // it's a good practice to refresh the access token also when the app becomes active.
    // This gives apps that seldom make api calls a higher chance of having a non expired
    // access token.
    [[self facebook] extendAccessTokenIfNeeded];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    NSLog(@"url->%@",url);
    return [self.facebook handleOpenURL:url];
}
- (BOOL)isFBLoggedIn
{
    return [facebook isSessionValid];
}

- (void)login
{
    if (![facebook isSessionValid])
    {
        [facebook authorize:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"offline_access", nil]];

    } else
    {
        [facebook logout];
        [facebook authorize:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"offline_access", nil]];
    }
}
- (void)fetchFBFriends
{
    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];
}
-(void)fetchFbDetails
{
    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];
}
- (void)storeAuthData:(NSString *)accessToken expiresAt:(NSDate *)expiresAt
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:accessToken forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:expiresAt forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}

    NSString *strRes = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=name,username,email,gender,birthday,hometown,picture&access_token=%@",facebook.accessToken]] usedEncoding:&encoding error:&error];

    NSMutableDictionary *dirFbDetails = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[strRes JSONValue]];

    -(void)fbDidExtendToken:(NSString *)accessToken expiresAt:(NSDate *)expiresAt
    {
        NSLog(@"token extended");
        [self storeAuthData:accessToken expiresAt:expiresAt];
    }
    -(void)doFaceBookLogin
    {
        [self.facebook authorize:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"friends_birthday",@"user_birthday",@"email",@"publish_stream",nil]];

    }
    #pragma mark - FBRequestDelegate Methods

    - (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
    {

    }
    - (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result
    {
    }

    - (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
    {


        NSLog(@"Err message: %@", [[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"error_msg"]);
        NSLog(@"Err code: %d", [error code]);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to say using FB sdk 3.5.x for iOS, this seems inconsistent with your answer.