# Facebook iOS SDK Login with UIWebView instead of safari (Native trick/solution)

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, authorization, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to utilize login process via Facebook`s iOS SDK, however, the login process is implemented via safari, instead of UIWebView. Is there any native way to fix this behavior? Or at least a simple/elegant solution?

```
let fbLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
            fbLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], handler: {
                (result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
                if ((error) != nil){
                }
                else if (result.isCancelled){
                } else {
                    if(result.grantedPermissions.contains("email")){
                        print(result)
                    }
                }
            })
```

Comment: You can find some solution here:
1. [Answer1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714699/login-facebook-right-in-app-with-embedded-webview-login-dialog)

2. [Answer2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313225/how-can-i-get-uiwebview-to-open-facebook-login-page-in-response-to-the-oauth-req)
3. [Answer3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870492/facebook-ios-sdk-login-native-and-uiwebview-login?rq=1)
hope those link can help you.

Comment: Thank you very much! Second answer did the job! I knew I was close in my guesses with loginBehavior...

Comment: ok, I've wrote an answer so you can mark the question as answered

Comment: @driver733 can you tell me how did you get this problem solved?

Comment: @GaneshKumar see `FBSDKLoginBehavior` reference [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKLoginManager/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find some nice solutions here:

1. [Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714699/login-facebook-right-in-app-with-embedded-webview-login-dialog)
2. [Solutions 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313225/how-can-i-get-uiwebview-to-open-facebook-login-page-in-response-to-the-oauth-req)
3. [Solutions 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870492/facebook-ios-sdk-login-native-and-uiwebview-login?rq=1)